# php replace tag with regex

Tags: php, regex

I searched in many forums about replacing the text between a tag, but all I get is how to remove text between tags etc. That's not what I'm looking for. Here is a little example so you can understand what I'm talking about.
I want to replace:

```
<form action="link1" method="post" name="form" id="form">
```

What I want to do is to get rid of this form and changes it to:

```
<form action="link2" ....>
```

Now, my problem is not about replacing but with choosing form tag.
I hope you understand me.

Comment: Sorry not able to understand. put some sort of code and specify your problem and also tell your expected outcome.

Comment: ohhh I want to use the php function str_replace('#(<form.*?>).*?(>)#','action="http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/",$content1);

Comment: I want to replace the whole <form> tag of start only not </form>

Comment: now I think my idea is clear

Comment: Are you just wanting to change the action attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You have structured data (html are structured data), so use this structure. What you want to do is to change an attribute value, it's easy with DOMDocument:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($yourHTML);

$formTagList = $dom->getElementsByTagName('form');

foreach ($formTagList as $formNode) {
    if ($formNode->hasAttribute('action') && $formNode->getAttribute('action') === 'link1')
        $formNode->setAttribute('action', 'link2');
}

$result = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a regular expression, then you should use preg_replace - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php. If you have a sample document, and the output you want, that would help too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but basing in your sample it's pretty simple. You can use this regex:

```
<form.*?>
```

And the replacement string

```
<form action="link2" ....>
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/mI6dW5/1)**

Php code

```
$re = "/<form.*?>/"; 
$str = "<form action=\"link1\" method=\"post\" name=\"form\" id=\"form\"></form>"; 
$subst = "<form action=\"link2\" ....>"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

//result:
//     <form action="link2" ....></form>
```